# Builtins and Closures in R

Tags: r

I don't know , if this is the correct place to ask subjective questions and I am fairly new to R, but i am really confused at this time.I was going through R-Language reference and found two objects by running `typeof(is.na)` and `typeof(mean)` which returned "builtin" and "closure" respectively on R prompt. I don't know what does it mean, I went to this site after searching, http://www.r-bloggers.com/closures-in-r-a-useful-abstraction/ , but unable to understand , Can anyone help me in understanding "closure" and "builtin" in some layman terms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `help("closure")`:

> This type of function is not the only type in R: they are called
>   closures (a name with origins in LISP) to distinguish them from
>   primitive functions.

From `help(".Primitive")`:

> a ‘primitive’ (internally implemented) function.

"internally implemented" is just a different term for "builtin".

Both (closures and primitives) are functions in R. A primitive function is implemented exclusively in C (with a special calling mechanism), a closure (mostly) in R.

Another distinction between them is, that a closure always has an environment associated with it (see [the language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Function-objects)). That's actually pretty much the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) of "closure".

Comment: Does this mean that - A closure is written in R using R syntax  whereas the builtin is written in c programming language?

Comment: That is my understanding. However, a closure can also call C code. E.g., if you look at the code of `mean.default` you see that in the end it calls `.Internal(mean(x))`.

Comment: In my R console, `help("Primitive")` did not work, but `help("primitive")` works. R is case sensitive. So, shouldn't it be help("primitive") above?

Comment: @ErdoganCEVHER This answer is 5 years old. It might have been different back then. Or it's an auto-correct typo.

Answer (score 3):

function clousures, or simply functions, are made of three basic components: formals, body and environment.

The environment, or better the enclosing environment, of a function is the environment where the function is created and functions do remember it ...

```
> typeof(mean)
[1] "closure"
> environment(mean)
<environment: namespace:base>
> environment(function(x){x+1})
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Primitives, as opposite to closures, do not have an environment:

```
> typeof(sum)          
[1] "builtin"
> environment(sum)
NULL
```

In practice, closures and Primitives, differ in the way arguments are passed to the internal function.

If we want to check if a function is a closure or primitive, we may use:

```
> is.primitive(sum)          
[1] TRUE
> is.primitive(mean)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: It would be helpful and nicer to give a concrete example for your statement/claim: _closures and Primitives, differ in the way arguments are passed to the internal function_.